# The filling of form fields is not supported(Firefox only)

Tags: acrofields

I have an editable PDF in which I want to bind some fields in my controller. It was working fine in chrome but firefox shows below message.
"This PDF document contains forms. The filling of form fields is not supported. Open with different Viewer."

Answer (score 1):

Not implemented in Firefox's built-in PDF player.  If you're opening a PDF with FireFox's built-in PDF player, you will not be able to use it as a fill-able form. Adobe pdf plugins are no longer supported. Open in Adobe Reader.
I found this link:
https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1160095

Answer (score 0):

It seems that FF v81 is going to have this feature.

Here is the [ghacks announce](https://www.ghacks.net/2020/08/03/firefox-81-pdf-reader-gets-form-filling-capabilities-and-more/).

Answer (score 0):

Latest update :
V81 has it.
This feature is disabled by default, To enable it

> Enter about:config in the URL bar and check the **pdfjs.renderInteractiveForms** preference. It is False by default, change it to True

[Mozilla support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1305496)